# R: Install Packages on Server to Non-Default version of R

Tags: r

I have my own R package saved as a `mypackage.tar.gz`file. I would like to install this package onto a server using the non-default version of R. So far, I have thought of something like:

`"/dir/R-x.x-x/bin/R" CMD INSTALL mypackage.tar.gz`

But have had little success.

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do:

1. Keep "the other R" off to the side
2. Expand the path to include it: `PATH="/opt/newR/bin:$PATH`
3. Use that when you call R:  `PATH="/opt/newR/bin:$PATH" R CMD INSTALL ...`
4. Simply tell the `R CMD INSTALL` in 3. where to put things via `--library | -l`

All together now:

`PATH="/opt/newR/bin:$PATH" R CMD INSTALL -l /opt/newRlib/ xts`

Comment: Oops. Copy and paste luser that I am. Fixing too.